# Close gracefully a UWP app from an external process

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have an UWP app and I would like to close it gracefully from a .NET console application. I tried `Process.CloseMainWindow`, but it does not work (it returns false). Conversely, `Process.Kill` works but the process is not closed gracefully. Is there an alternative way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we have an API for doing this - AppResourceGroupInfo.StartTerminateAsync():

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startterminateasync#Windows_System_AppResourceGroupInfo_StartTerminateAsync

Comment: i suppose that this requires the external executable to be in same installation package as the app right ?

Comment: @XeorgeXeorge No it doesn't. It can be an external plain app (Win32 or .NET) or an external app package. If you do the latter, be sure to declare the 'appDiagnostics' capability.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT This works if a try to close a UWP app from another UWP app, right? The problem is that I would like to close an UWP app from a non-UWP console application

Comment: This API can also be called from non-UWP applications.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT How about from Windows PowerShell? How to close e.g. Calculator in Win10 1909 without using cmdlet Stop-Process?

Comment: Can I somehow call this from Powershell script in order to close UWP app ?